# Visa and Immigration delays on arrival in Denpasar, Bali, Indonesia

Tags: visas, airports, indonesia, bali

Denpasar Airport in Bali recently [expanded the international terminal](http://www.thejakartapost.com/news/2011/08/22/ngurah-rai-airport-kicks-massive-expansion-project.html). Prior to the expansion, arrival in the evening would usually be accompanied by an hour-plus wait to get a visa voucher and get through immigration due to the large amount of flights arriving around the same time.

Has the wait gotten more tolerable after the international terminal expansion, or is it more or less the same as before the airport expansion?

Comment: Is your question title supposed to read "Immigration AND visa" or "Immigration visa"? People may misconstrue the meaning.

Comment: @drN, apologies, I edited it. Basically, you go to a little window, pay $35 at a little window to get some form that says you have paid for the visa, then you line up at immigration to actually get the visa stamp in your passport. This is usually horribly congested with tourists from around the world and takes time in a hot airport room. Just curious to see if things have changed. If nobody knows, I will just self-answer in a couple weeks.

Comment: Came in on 1 4 Aug 2014 and had to wait in the queue for 3 hrs 45 mins.

Comment: @jmac If you are so worried about the queue, why not get your passport in advance from an Indonesian consulate (bonus: you can get a 30 or 60 days visa)? I believe the process is pretty standard across countries, see how to do it from the one in Singapore http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48200/how-to-get-a-60-days-indonesian-tourist-visa-from-singapore

Comment: @AdrienBe thanks for the info -- had no idea that was doable. It is both more costly (in time and fee) to do it before leaving, but I suppose it is an option.

Comment: @jmac actually, it's probably worth it for the 60 days visa as it avoids having to request an extension which can be complicated/stressful in some places but also total to the same price or even more. A 60 days Indonesian tourist visa costs circa 48 USD in Singapore. Versus a 30 days Indonesian voa costing $30 plus extension for $25 (if not more, i.e. if you go through an agency), so a total of minimum 55 USD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal is bigger (and now air conditioned!) but the lines for entry are no better than before. In addition, the government has encouraged travel agencies not to provide "VIP service" where you can pay $30 or so to skirt the line. The travel agent I spoke with said that the restriction would probably be loosened again in 3 months or so.

"VIP Service" is still available for departures, but the former lines for security before getting to ticket counters no longer exists (the ticket counters are prior to the security check point), so the service is not of that much use.