# How to obtain a 60-day Indonesian tourist visa in Singapore?

Tags: visas, paperwork, singapore, indonesia

I am in Singapore and I want to get an Indonesian 60-day tourist visa.

Do you know and have experience with the process?

Note: A big advantage of a 60-day tourist visa over a 30-day visa on arrival is that [the 60-day tourist visa can be extended four times for 30 days each](http://www.lashworldtour.com/2013/09/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-tourist-or-social-visa.html), so you can stay for a total of 180 days (60+4x30).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to get a 60-day tourist visa at the Indonesian Consulate in Singapore.

---

#### Documents to provide:

- 65 **Singapore dollars** in cash - they do **not** accept card payments, and they only accept Singapore dollars.
- Photo ID - although you can do one inside the consulate
- Copy of passport - although you can do one in consulate for 50 cents. Passport must have at least 6 months remaining validity.
- Copy of proof of travel to Indonesia - i.e. Ferry ticket or plane ticket. Ferry ticket to Batam works fine.
- Copy of proof of onward travel: I had bought a ferry ticket back to Singapore and they told me this was not needed. But other people, like Ashish (see his answer), might have to provide one. So just bring one to be on the safe side, i.e. Ferry ticket from Batam to Singapore.
- Additionally, bring something of value to leave at the entrance (a deposit to leave against the badge they lend you for your visit at the consulate): an ID card, or a bank card, or a smartphone (I only had that and they accepted it!), or else.

---

#### Opening times:

- Seems like **mornings** are for visa applications: from 09:00 to 12:00
- Seems like **afternoons** are for picking up visas: from 15:00 to 17:00

---

#### Dress code:

- No tank top
- No shorts
- Flip flops not ok in theory but fine in practice (everyone was wearing them).

Another thing: there are toilets just before the entrance of the embassy, so that you can get changed there if needed.

---

#### Get there:

You can get there by metro, station [Orchard](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/ion+orchard/@1.303517,103.832224,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x5cbe8874aa0b1b37?sa=X&ei=yDdjVYHaA4TjuQSPo4LYBA&ved=0CIEBEPwSMA8). Then walk around 10 minutes to get there.

See the [Indonesian Consulate on Google Map](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Embassy+of+the+Republic+of+Indonesia/@1.3029999,103.8394461,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x31da198813a33209:0xca748ea508407f1).

The address is: Embassy of the Republic of Indonesia, 7 Chatsworth Rd, Singapore  249761

---

#### Delay:

- When I went there, the process was very straightforward and fast. I probably didn't spend more than 15 minutes at the embassy.
- Processing your application takes 2 to 3 working days. In my case, I had to go get my visa 2 days later (applied the Monday morning, picked up the visa on Wednesday).

---

#### Resources

You can (and should) double-check all this info by visiting at least [the official website of the embassy of the Republic of Indonesia in Singapore](http://www.kemlu.go.id/singapore/Pages/default.aspx?l=en).

Further details also on:

- http://www.travelfish.org/visas_detail/singapore/7
- http://www.travelinput.com/indonesian-visa-in-singapore/#.VWJ2B1meDGc
- [How to extend Indonesian visa on arrival (VOA) in Indonesia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/991/how-to-extend-indonesian-visa-on-arrival-voa-in-indonesia)
- http://boards.bootsnall.com/singapore-to-sumatra-t30735.html

---

#### Result

You will have such a big stamp in your passport, yes it takes a whole page.

[image: Indonesian 60 days Tourist Visa]

Answer (score 7):

Adrien's answer is spot on. Except for one thing. I just went to the embassy for visa application and they required me to have a return ticket. I am an Indian national. It may be different in my case. So I booked a ticket ticket from phone, went to lucky plaza to get a printout and joined the queue again. I got out in 20 minutes after that.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks for letting everyone know. I'll update my answer to match your experience