# Getting a 60 day visa for Bali while in Singapore for 2 nights

Tags: visas, international-travel, singapore, bali

Can I pay extra fee for one day turnaround time for 60 day visa at Indonesian consulate in Singapore?

Comment: What passport/citizenship do you hold?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the current rules for many foreigners going to Indonesia are:

- Free visa on arrival for 30 days, not extendable.
- 35 USD visa on arrival for 30 days, extendable once to total of 60 days.

So you probably (depends on your nationality, which you omitted) do not need to get any visa before going to Bali.  Since you'll only be in Singapore for two days, you may want to save time there by spending the extra few minutes in the VoA queue at Bali (half of which will consist of confused foreigners who haven't heard that VoA is free for 30 days now--it was not this way until recently).

Comment: Also, per http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48200/how-to-obtain-a-60-day-indonesian-tourist-visa-in-singapore, the processing time in Singapore is 2-3 working days.